# Export const object deriving from class with methods in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm kind of new to typescript.  I have a generic class

```
export class Sample {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    doSomething(): any {
        // return something
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a default constant object, but am running into an issue because I'm not defining doSomething.  Shouldn't defaultSample automatically inherit the base functionality of doSomething, or am I missing something?

```
export const defaultSample: Sample {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}
```

Comment: Types are erased at compile time, so `: Sample` doesn't have any effect on object at runtime. For inheritance (prototype) you'll need to `new Sample ...`

Answer (score 0):

Hey TypeScript types doesn't provide you such functionality, all types of typescript are deleted when you run your code, but you can do it like this to achieve the functionality you want:

```
export class Sample {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    doSomething(): any {
        // return something
    }
}
class defaultSample extends Sample {
 a = 1;
 b = 2;
}

const x = new defaultSample()
```

then the new class will have your a and b and the inherited function `doSomething` or you can create a constructor in your `Sample` class:

```
class Sample {
    constructor(a, b) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
    }
    a;
    b;
    doSomething() {
        // return something
    }
}

export const defaultSample = new Sample(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing there, is stating the type of `defaultSample`. That's why you are getting the error.

You have two options here. You can create a new instance of `Sample` and assign it to `defaultSample`

```
export class Sample {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    doSomething(): any {
        // return something
    }
}

const defaultSample = new Sample();
defaultSample.a = 1;
```

You can also add a constructor for setting `a` and `b`.

The second option, if you really want the inheritance, is creating a class and *extending* `Sample` class.

```
export class Sample {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    doSomething(): any {
        // return something
    }
}

class DefaultSample extends Sample {
 a = 1;
 b = 2;
}

const myDefaultSample = new DefaultSample();
```